# Contractors vs contractuals

Tags: word-usage, difference, terminology

How do I use "contractors" and "contractuals" correctly?  Some of my colleagues believe they are interchangeable and mean the same thing. I have done some research and believe the word contractor is used for somebody that works under a contract and contractual is part of the written contract.

Answer (score 2):

You are basically correct. "Contractual" is an adjective, that pretty much exclusively refers to the contract agreement. "Contractor" is a noun, and it means someone who works under the terms of contract. So a contractor may be contractually required to fill the contractual obligations of the contract.

Comment: Yes, but because it's pluralized, fairly obviously OP is citing the use of the adjective ***contractuals*** as a noun, to mean *obligations* or *clauses* within a contract. That's not a usage/sense listed in OED, but it's typical of management-speak jargon.

Comment: I don't recall ever hearing "contractual" used as a noun, and it's not listed as a noun in any of the dictionaries I just checked. But MBA types love to abuse the language this way. This page -- http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780240806204500100 -- defines a "contractual" as "a charge that cannot be attached to any particular phase of production, but rather applies to the budget as a whole".

Comment: Huh. I've never heard that before, but I assume it's a nominal adjective, standing in for "contractual obligations".

Answer (score 0):

We use "Contractual(s)", as a noun to define and classify the employees, not in a pay-roll, while subcontracted to an employer, by a main employer.